# Crystal Reports fail to log in

Tags: database, authentication, crystal-reports-2008

I made a Crystal Report and it works if I use it in with the same DB info I used to create it. But when I use the report in another context (say, from develop, to testing) it doesn't work. The error is "Failed to log in".

What it doesn't make sense is that I give the DB parameters with: SetDatabaseLogon() function. But as I research on the internet, it seems that sometimes I should iterate over all tables of the report and set this information for each one. So, I don't get then what the SetDatabaseLogon() info does.

The developing DB and testing DB are from the same provider, it only changes the SQL Server name (even user and pass are the same).

I'd appreciate any help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your report contains any subreport, then you have to loop through all the subreports in the main reports and set SetDatabaseLogon() info